# Is there a NuGet equivalent for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, nuget

Starting out with Visual Studio on a new job. I was introduced to NuGet for installing packages in VS. Is there any such applications for Eclipse?

I was using Eclipse ( am not an expert)

Answer (score 10):

The equivalent for Java projects would be Maven or similar (Ivy, Gradle, etc.)

There are a couple of Maven plugins for Eclipse, like [m2eclipse](http://www.sonatype.org/m2eclipse/).

In general, Java dependency management is handled via tools like this. One reason is to remove the IDE from the build equation, since developers may use different IDEs, there might be a CI server involved (i.e., no IDE at all), IDE versions might break/change the build process, etc.

IMO relying on the IDE for building is an environmental smell.

Comment: Definitely agree that relying on the IDE is not a Good Thing for an ecosystem. NuGet has the command line tool which can be invoked from anywhere. Just getting started on Android development, I can't believe there isn't something like this for the Java ecosystem.

Comment: @itsjason : ...but there is? Both Maven and Gradle mentioned in the answer can be invoked from the command line, and they both are tools for downloading dependencies to the project from repositories. Gradle is the new kid in town, embraced by Google, and should be preferred for Android development.

Comment: No, there isn't. Nuget does strictly, only, package management. If you want a build tool in the .NET world, you use MSBuild or nant. The concerns aren't mixed.

Comment: I would upvote this answer if it didn't contain the erroneous assumption that NuGet (or the build system, while we're at it) is a part of the IDE.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper OK, but I find it odd, since I explicitly state it, and similar tools, are completely separate from the IDE, by design.

Comment: @DaveNewton: NuGet *is* completely separate from the IDE. Your answer does not mention that. Instead, it *appears* to imply that NuGet is tightly linked to the IDE, in contrast to Java tools, which are not.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I understand the words you're saying, couldn't disagree more, and don't even know how your arrived at your conclusion. I don't discuss the NuGet environment at all and state that the equivalent are other non-IDE tools. Whatever.

Answer (score 2):

[jpm4j](https://www.jpm4j.org/) is a package manager for java.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Ivy would be the equivalent of NuGet.